# How to make IIS7 stop adding etag to response headers?

Tags: iis-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [yslow says etags are misconfigured. how to configure etags properly on IIS7 ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/55919/yslow-says-etags-are-misconfigured-how-to-configure-etags-properly-on-iis7)

For performance reasons, I'm using expire headers for static files (adding long expiration periods like 50 years or so).

Now I'm trying to get rid of etag headers which are automatically added by IIS7. I've done some searching but it seems harder than what I thought (there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way). I found some workarounds but they all use httpmodules (which I'm keeping as a last resort). I strongly prefer to not get the etag header added in the first place. Did anyone manage to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting you can change, which will prevent the tags from being generated/included. The best you can do with settings is make sure the etags which are generated, are empty.

If you do want to remove them altogether, you'll need to rely on modules and/or custom code.