# disable etag in IIS 7

Tags: iis, performance, etags

Does anyone know how I can disable [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) on IIS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't make it easy. In fact, the only way I've found to do it requires installing a 3rd party plugin. At that point, the performance benefit of removing etags is questionable.

Comment: never found a good solution for it so left it alone.

Answer (score 3):

As I answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/55919/yslow-says-etags-are-misconfigured-how-to-configure-etags-properly-on-iis7) (different question, same answer):

> Open your IIS manager, click on the
>   server, and go to HTTP Response
>   Headers. Click the "Add..." button,
>   and under name, enter:
>
> ETag
>
> (case sensitive). Under Value, enter
>
> ""
>
> (thats two double quotes)
>
> And ETags begone!

Comment: Even after doing that it still writes

ETag:·"9111cdf83dc3cb1:0",""